# Griffon JMX Plugin 0.3 don't work.(update descript)

Tags: groovy, jmx, griffon

Griffon JMX Plugin 0.3 don't work.
anyone use this version

1.got error: no lib folder

then i download the src, cp lib/griffon-jmx-addon-0.3.jar

2.create a service

```
class SmsManagerService {
    static expose = ['jmx:service=Country,type=special']
    def serviceMethod() {
        "a"
    }
}
```

3.run-app && connect by jconsole, by did not find my mbean.
am i missing some step? plz help,thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: You might want to rephrase this as an actual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andres Almiray  :

## 1 fixed in version 0.4 of the plugin

## 2 you are selection the wrong Java process. You must select the process that runs the application (griffon.swing.SwingApplication) not the one that runs the griffon command (o.c.g.GriffonMain).

## 3 JmxGriffonAddon and JmxGriffonPlugin are the only sources needed by the plugin